# MySql Correlated subqueries implementation

Tags: java, sql, correlated-subquery

For the below query :

```
SELECT Id, Salary
FROM Employee e
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Salary) FROM Employee p
           WHERE e.Salary<=p.Salary)
```

Shouldn't the `e.salary<=p.salary` condition in the subquery be reversed . We should be comparing the p.salary column with the `e.salary` column from the outer query repeatedly and hence `p.salary` must be on the left  hand side. Please let me know if my understanding is wrong .

PS: the above query is trying to find the second highest salary from Employee table.

Edit : The issue seems to be in my understanding . I have mentioned below how i feel the query maybe executed :

Say we have a table Employee with 4 salaries 10,20,30,40 . Now the records start getting processed one by one . So we kind of get the following 4 intermediate implementations :

```
`code`
SELECT Id, Salary
FROM Employee e
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.Salary)
           FROM Employee p
           WHERE 10<=p.salary    -- record with salary 10
          );
SELECT Id, Salary
FROM Employee e
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.Salary)
           FROM Employee p
           WHERE 20<=p.salary
          );
SELECT Id, Salary
FROM Employee e
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.Salary)
           FROM Employee p
           WHERE 30<=p.salary
          );
SELECT Id, Salary
FROM Employee e
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.Salary)
           FROM Employee p
           WHERE 40<=p.salary
          );
`code`
```

Is this order correct ? Shouldn't the column we are trying to compare i.e p.salary must be on the left side like `p.salary>=e.salary` ?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: This query looks correct to me.  Do you have an actual problem?

Comment: The condition in the `WHERE` clause says count the number of salaries which are >= the current row, and make sure that this number is =2 ... in other words, take the second highest salary.

Comment: I am using oracle . The query works fine. The problem i am getting here is like the inner query executes on basis of the salary from the outer query . So we must be taking the column of inner query in the left hand side ? Like simple example , if the outer query's first table record is having a salary say 100 , now if u write this in the above inner query , it becomes somewhat like this :
 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Salary) FROM Employee p
           WHERE 100<=p.Salary)

Is this logically correct ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the query:

```
SELECT Id, Salary
FROM Employee e
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.Salary)
           FROM Employee p
           WHERE e.Salary <= p.Salary
          );
```

It is counting the number of *distinct* salaries that are greater or equal to any given employee's salary.  That is, the query calculates the second largest salary taking ties into account.

If you "reverse" the conditions, you'll be doing something else.

In most databases, you can express this using `dense_rank()` instead of such a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT Id, Salary
FROM (SELECT e.*,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY e.salary) as dr
      FROM Employee e
     ) e
WHERE dr = 2;
```

Comment: I guess i need to work out the logic again . Say we have a table Employee with 4 salaries 10,20,30,40 . Now the records start getting processed one by one . So we kind of get the following 4 intermediate implementations :

SELECT Id, Salary
FROM Employee e
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.Salary)
           FROM Employee p
           WHERE e.Salary <=10
          );

Comment: check the question please . I have modified the question